# Does g++ optimizes x / 2^n multiplication?

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

Will g++ optimize x * 2<sup>n</sup> expression to `x << n`? Like this:
(The same with division)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr int n = 16;

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x * n << std::endl;
}
```

to

```cpp
std::cout << (x << 4) << std::endl;
```

Comment: If you want to know, see: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: I think you mean `x << 4`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Of course, that presumes the OP can understand the assembly code, which is not a given.

Comment: @FredLarson Not really.  You don't need to understand what it does to see if the same assembly is generated.

Comment: "The same with division" - careful: *signed* division by a power of two is not exactly equivalent to a right shift. It is close though, and it can be optimized *using* a right shift, it's just not that simple.

Comment: @NathanOliver Assemblies are slightly different, but I don't understand it.

Comment: That means it doesn't optimize it to a shift then, if the assembly is different.

Comment: Did you remember to add optimization flags (e.g. `-O2` or even `-O3`)?

Comment: @harold It refers only to division, or to multuplication too?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now with flags - `-O3` optimizes, others non.

Comment: @Gordem multiplication does not have that complication